# Variable 'observer' might not have been initialized

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am trying to remove the observer after the first callback. I am not having any luck.

```
Observer <? super List<MyEntity>> observer = new Observer<List<MyEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<MyEntity> myEntities) {
        Log.d(TAG, "observer changed");

       //Variable 'observer' might not have been initialized error here
       MySearchViewModel.getMyList().removeObserver(observer);
    }
};
MySearchViewModel.getMyList().observe(MainActivity.this, observer);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does `removeObserver(this)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mrteddy. Here is the correct code:

```
Observer <? super List<MyEntity>> observer = new Observer<List<MyEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<MyEntity> myEntities) {

       MySearchViewModel.getMyList().removeObserver(this);
    }
};
MySearchViewModel.getMyList().observe(MainActivity.this, observer);
```